# error with using android and SHOWasAction attribute to make the menu bar appear

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, compiler-errors

i need to have a menu or an action bar  that must be display when the user  use the application  but the problem is that the menu items do not show  only ofter i click the menu button on the emulator   can anyone help me ????

## test.java

```
package com.example.test;

import com.example.test.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class test extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## mani_activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/twitter"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="twitter"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="facebook"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:title="refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        />


</menu>
```

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".test"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: You mean to say that the menu items don't show up at all right now?  You shouldn't need the code below until you need to react to the menu item clicks (which you will need, but not to resolve your problem if that is the case).

Comment: yes the items do not show at all unless i press the menu button on the emulator wish not what i need

Comment: Oh, then it doesn't sound as though you want to be using menu items.  If you want something that is there all the time then it will probably be best to create your own UI component to handle options or use an ActionBar as your second thought that you brought forward.  Menu items are meant to be hidden until needed.

Comment: @LebDev  lol? is that spelling mistake? mani_activity_menu.xml that might be the reason?

Comment: @ Metalhead1247 lol sorry  error typing  no it is main

Comment: @ Jay Snayder  so the action bar will do the job that mean will  the items still always displayed ??

Answer (score 0):

Tried  your code . Its working  without any problems

You have made spelling mistake at mani_activity_menu.xml ?

Add

`setHasOptionsMenu(true);` //in oncreate

`item.setEnabled(false);` //add this in oncreated option

```
  package com.example.exammmm;



   import android.os.Bundle;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/85a2/3pgc2sdoh5k7zb1fg.jpg))</sub>

Read -----> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @ Metalhead1247 yes i get these items but after i press the menu button in the emulator and what i need that is to make these items displayed always  without click the menu button

Comment: @LebDev  add this in oncreate  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  setHasOptionsMenu(true)

Comment: the system does not allow me to add the  setHasOptionsMenu(true)  it display an error

Comment: the error is : The method setHasOptionsMenu(boolean) is undefined for the type test

Comment: @LebDev which theme are you using?

Comment: @ Metalhead1247  i edit my question and add the style.xml file